# Почему SELECT через mysqli получает количество строк, но не получает их значения?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

У меня есть запрос:

```
$selpublist = $mysqli->query("SELECT `vk_id` FROM `groups`", MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

На локальном сервере он работал, а после переезда на хостинг он отказывается работать. `var_dump($selpublist)`:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(17) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

С БД всё нормально, phpmyadmin выбирает всё тоже нормально. Хостер говорит что это не их проблема. Версия php 5.3.

После выполнения запроса я вывожу данные через цикл:

```
foreach ( $selpublist as $group ) { }
```

Что делать?

Comment: Так [примеры](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) надо смотреть как правильно делать

Comment: @BOPOH я вывожу полученный результат с помощью цикла, а цикл ничего не выводит.

Comment: а примеры хоть смотрели? там цикл по-другому сделан: `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {...}`, это далеко не то же самое, что у вас

Comment: @BOPOH но почему-то раньше и этот цикл работал.

Comment: @BOPOH так заработало. Если хотите, напишите ответ, чтобы я отметил его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читать документацию http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

> Возвращает FALSE в случае неудачи. В случае успешного выполнения запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN mysqli_query() вернет объект mysqli_result. Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query() вернет TRUE.

И дальше про [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php)

```
mysqli_result::$current_field — Получает смещение указателя по отношению к текущему полю
mysqli_result::data_seek — Перемещает указатель результата на выбранную строку
mysqli_result::fetch_all — Выбирает все строки из результирующего набора и помещает их в ассоциативный массив, обычный массив или в оба
mysqli_result::fetch_array — Выбирает одну строку из результирующего набора и помещает ее в ассоциативный массив, обычный массив или в оба
mysqli_result::fetch_assoc — Извлекает результирующий ряд в виде ассоциативного массива
mysqli_result::fetch_field_direct — Получение метаданных конкретного поля
mysqli_result::fetch_field — Возвращает следующее поле результирующего набора
mysqli_result::fetch_fields — Возвращает массив объектов, представляющих поля результирующего набора
mysqli_result::fetch_object — Возвращает текущую строку результирующего набора в виде объекта
mysqli_result::fetch_row — Получение строки результирующей таблицы в виде массива
mysqli_result::$field_count — Получение количества полей в результирующем наборе
mysqli_result::field_seek — Установить указатель поля на определенное смещение
mysqli_result::free — Освобождает память занятую результатами запроса
mysqli_result::$lengths — Возвращает длины полей текущей строки результирующего набора
mysqli_result::$num_rows — Получает число рядов в результирующей выборке
```

Comment: Я после получения данных вывожу с помощью цикла, но ничего не выводится. Я обновил вопрос.